# How can I add a directive to a component that's injected after a <router-outlet>

Tags: angular

I have a component that is loaded via a `<router-outlet>`:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'sandbox',
    templateUrl: 'sandbox.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['sandbox.component.css']
})
export class SandboxComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() myDirective;

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Invoked from the following `router-link` to the `<router-outlet>`:

```
<a routerLink="sandbox">{{i18n.sandbox}}</a>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Angular is rendering the `<sandbox>` component immediately following the `<router-outlet>`:

```
<a routerLink="sandbox">{{i18n.sandbox}}</a>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<sandbox>
    Sandbox Text
</sandbox>
```

When Angular renders `<sandbox>` I want it to unconditionally add a (`myDirective`) to the `<sandbox>` element within the rendered `HTML` as follows:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<sandbox>
    <div myDirective>
        Sandbox Text
    </div>
</sandbox>
```

I am able to get the effect of `myDirective` within `<sandbox>` by nesting a `<div myDirective>` as an immediate child of `<sandbox>` within the `<sandbox>`template, but don't like adding the `<div>` simply to apply a directive.

Is there a way to unconditionally add `myDirective` to an element injected / rendered from a `router-link`?

Comment: Did you test it and is not working? I'm using angular router 3.0.0 and the fact that a component (or any other element) is placed below the router outlet has nothing to do with the rendering. The sandbox component should be pushed downwards in the dom. Is there. It doesn't go away (i tested it in my app just now). Please make sure you setup the directive correctly - take out the div. Use @Input() my-directive on the sandbox component and then  if you still have problems let me know.

Comment: I altered the code as you suggested and `my-directive` is still not being added to the `<sandbox>` element. (I've also altered the code snippet (above) to reflect how the code is presently written). Regarding if the directive is correct - it works properly when I attach it to the containing `<div>` and in other places (not represented in the code sample) - so my guess is that the `my-directive` is OK...\

Comment: I checked again and i can tell for sure that it has nothing to do with the router outlet. Can you place the code of your directive for us to see? Just now i created a brand new directive, i set the background color red and it wasn't working on the component. It worked on the div though. But font-size of 45 px worked on both. Maybe is some unexpected behaviour resulting form the way angular creates this DOM trees. Hmm..

Comment: @AIon - I've adjusted my question - we were on different wavelengths here - it's not that the component was after the `<router-outlet>` - it's the component that is dynamically rendered following the `<router-outlet>` as the result of a `router-link` being clicked (e.g. the component only comes into existence within the page after the user clicks the `router-link`) - I can't find a way to add a directive to this dynamically rendered component (in this case `<sandbox>`)